# The meaning of the Keep combination?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I am trying to under the `Keep` combination in akka streams and created the following example:

```
import java.nio.file.Paths

import akka.NotUsed
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.{ActorMaterializer, IOResult}
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{FileIO, Flow, Keep, Sink, Source}
import akka.util.ByteString

import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}

object FileConsumer extends App {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("reactive-tweets")
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  val source: Source[Int, NotUsed] = Source(1 to 100)
  val factorials = source.scan(BigInt(1))((acc, next) => acc * next)

  val result: Future[IOResult] =
    factorials.map(_.toString).runWith(lineSink("factorial2.txt"))

  implicit val ec = system.dispatcher
  result.onComplete {
    case Success(v) => println(s"Fileinfo ${ v.count }")
    case Failure(e) => println(e)
  }

  def lineSink(filename: String): Sink[String, Future[IOResult]] =
    Flow[String].map(s => ByteString(s + "\n")).toMat(FileIO.toPath(Paths.get(filename)))(Keep.right)


}
```

on the [akka streams website](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-quickstart.html) it says:

> The resulting blueprint is a `Sink[String, Future[IOResult]]`, which
>   means that it accepts strings as its input and when materialized it
>   will create auxiliary information of type `Future[IOResult]` (when
>   chaining operations on a Source or Flow the type of the auxiliary
>   information—called the “materialized value”—is given by the leftmost
>   starting point; since we want to retain what the `FileIO.toPath` sink
>   has to offer, we need to say `Keep.right`).

but what, when I want to keep the `ByteString` on the left side, I've tried:

```
  def lineSink2(filename: String): Sink[String, Future[ByteString]] =
Flow[String].map(s => ByteString(s + "\n")).toMat(Sink.foreach(println))(Keep.left)
```

but it does not compile at all.

I also do not understand:

> is given by the leftmost starting point

Is leftmost starting point the `Flow`?

I think, I do not understand the idea of `Keep` yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definition of Sink.foreach is as follows:

```
def foreach[T](f: T ⇒ Unit): Sink[T, Future[Done]]
```

That means materialised value is Future[Done]

In case of flow you have:

```
 val value: Flow[String, ByteString, NotUsed] = Flow[String].map(s => ByteString(s + "\n"))
```

**its materialised value is NotUsed**

In this case:

**Keep.left** - NotUsed - Materialised Value of Source or Flow

**Keep.right** - Future[Done] - Materalised Value of Sink

**Keep.both** - (NotUsed, Future[Done])

Important fact is materialised value in many cases is NOT value of elements  flowing through the stream, its rather

- diagnostic information
- stream state
- other kind of information about stream

Comment: Let me add that there is nothing special about `Keep.left` and `Keep.right`, they are very simple functions like `(l: Any, r: Any) => l`.
The akka team just provides them so the code is more readable.